# realloc(): invalid next size

Tags: c, valgrind, realloc

I read some threads on the forum regarding issues like these but I still can't figure it out.

I'm writing a stack implementation code and I am stuck on the part where I have to reallocate memory when the stack is full and make the array twice as large as before.

Here's my code for the push function;

```
typedef struct stackImp *Stack;
typedef int Item;

struct stackImp{
    Item * items;
    int top;
    int maxSize;

void push (Stack stack, Item item){ 
    assert(stack != NULL);
    Item *temp;
    if (stack->top < stack->maxSize+1) {
    stack->items[stack->top] = item;
    stack->top++;
    }
    else {
    temp = realloc(stack->items, 2*(stack->maxSize) * sizeof(Item));
    assert (temp != NULL);
    stack->items = temp;
    stack->items[stack->top] = item;
    stack->top++;
    stack->maxSize = (stack->maxSize)*2;
    } 
}
```

And the error I keep getting is: [image] 
The message from Valgrind: [image]

Can someone please explain what's going on?

Comment: Are we supposed to guess how `Stack` and `Item` are defined? Are they `struct` types? Show them.

Comment: Don't post error messages and Valgrind output as pictures or links to pictures. Include, wehenver possible, the relevant parts in the question. And try to reduce your code as much as possible.

Comment: Hint: `stack->items` value at that instance is not that one returned by `malloc()` or `realloc()`.

Comment: Posting pictures of code rather than text is a down-vote magnet.

Comment: @BrettHale Stack is a struct with an array of integers (Item is an int), top element, and the maxSize of the struct.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I don't understand could you please elaborate?

Comment: @BrettHale Hey sorry, I edited it in now

Answer (score 0):

You are off by one here:

```
if (stack->top < stack->maxSize+1) {
    stack->items[stack->top] = item;
```

Valid indexes for `stack->items[index]` is [0..maxSize-1], so you need to change the condition to:

```
if (stack->top < stack->maxSize) {
    stack->items[stack->top] = item;
```